# Question about a proof antiderivative of complex function.

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

Theorem:

Let $U\in \Bbb C $ be an open rectangle and $p\in U$.

Let $f,g \in C(U,\Bbb R)\cap C^1(U-\{p\},\Bbb R)$.

If $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial g}{\partial x} \;\;\text{on}\;\; U-\{p\}$$

Then $\exists h\in C^1(U,\Bbb R)$, such that $$\frac{\partial h}{\partial x}=f \;\;\text{and}\;\; \frac{\partial h}{\partial y}=g \;\;\text{on}\;\; U$$

Proof:

Fix a point $(a_0,b_0)\in U-\{p\}$ and define

$$h(x,y)=\int_{a_0}^x f(t,b_0)dt+\int_{b_0}^y g(t,s)ds\;\;\text{, for}\;(x,y)\in U$$

By fundamental theorem of Calculus, $$\frac{\partial h}{\partial y}=g \;\;\text{on}\;U$$

For y fixed, then let functions $$H(x)=h(x,y) $$ and $$F(x)=f(x,y)$$ are continuous on $U$ and $$H'(x)=F(x)$$ except possibly at $p_1$, where $p=(p_1,p_2)\;\;\color{darkorange}{(\star)}$.

Using the fact that:

If $H,F:(\alpha,\beta) \to \Bbb R$ are continuous, but $H'(x)=F(x) \;\;\forall x\in (\alpha,\beta)-\{p\}$, where $p\in (\alpha,\beta)$.

Then $H'(p)=F(p).$

Hence, $$H'(x)=F(x)\;\;\text{on}\;U$$

$\color{blue}{\textrm{My question on}}\;\;\color{darkorange}{(\star)}$

Why $H'(x)=F(x)$ except possibly at $p_1$, where $p=(p_1,p_2)$ ?

$F(x)=f(x,y)$ is continuous on $U$, hence, $F(x)=f(x,y)$ is continuous on $[p_1,a_0], so \int_{a_0}^{p_1} F(t)dt$ exists. By fundamental theorem of calculus, $$\frac{d}{dx}{\int_{a_0}^{p_1} F(t)dt}=F(p_1)$$

Does that mean $$H'(x)=F(x)\;\;\forall x\in U$$?

Thanks a lot!